# Postgresql boolean

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Postgresql stores boolean value TRUE or FALSE, while I am passing 1 or 0. And I want to store as 1 or 0 instead of TRUE or FALSE.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you need this?  What's wrong with `TRUE` and `FALSE`?  Also, `SELECT TRUE::integer, FALSE::integer;`

Comment: nothing issue with TRUE and FALSE but I want to stick to save 0 and 1 rather than TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: How is the table defined?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Store your data in a numeric type if you really want but this looks like a presentation issue rather than a data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have made data type as `Boolean`

If you want to save as 1 and 0 only, then you should make data type as `Small Int`

Then you will be able to save as 1 or 0 and retrieve the same.